# Liferay 7 OSGi module logs to console and file

Tags: tomcat, logging, liferay, liferay-7

I work with liferay 7 on tomcat 8. I created my own portlet as OSGi module and added logging to it.

in java class

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Log;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogFactoryUtil;
...
private static Log log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(ClassName.class);
...
log.info("Message");
```

in \main\resources\META-INF\module-log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender" name="file">
        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="${catalina.home}/logs/portlet-name.log" />
        </rollingPolicy>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}:%L] %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="packagename.classname">
        <level value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </logger>
</log4j:configuration>
```

This works and logs are written to /liferay/tomcat/logs/portlet-name.log file! But at the same time logs are written to console and to catalina.out file.

How to disable portlet logging in the console and leave it in a portlet-name.log file?

Answer (score 1):

Check tomcat's conf/logging.properties, there's a ConsoleHandler declared in there and various others. Most likely these are the culprits